# How to enable Flash on GoogleTV in the WebView

Tags: flash, webview, android-webview, google-tv

Does the WebView on the Google TV (Sony NSZ-GS7, OS 3.2) support the Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is not supported in Android WebView (Which includes Google TV).